# Facebook Cucumber testing with Authlogic - how test user logged in as facebook user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, cucumber, authlogic

I'm having trouble implementing this step:

```
Given "I am logged in as a Facebook user" do

end
```

The best suggestions I can find on the web (http://opensoul.org/2009/3/6/testing-facebook-with-cucumber) do not seem to be using Authlogic for authentication.

Can someone with the Cucumber/Authlogic_facebook_connect/Authlogic combo post their step for testing facebook logins?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://ryanbigg.com/2010/03/testing-facebook/. It might be helpful.

Comment: Excellent find! Thank you very much. That was perfect.